# Oracle ORDS get logged in user

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-ords

I successfully followed the steps 1-4 in section 3.5.5.3 at [3.5 Configuring Secure Access to RESTful Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56351_01/doc.30/e56293/develop.htm#AELIG90123) for first party cookie-based authentication and the resource is protected, so I login with hr_admin/password and successfully retrieve the resource.  How can I detect in the SQL that this is hr_admin?  I checked:

```
sys_context ('userenv','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')
sys_context ('userenv','CLIENT_IDENTIFIER')
sys_context ('userenv','CLIENT_INFO')
v('APP_USER')
```

among others but couldn't find the username (hr_admin) anywhere, everything points to the database schema (ORDSTEST).  The username I am after is the OAuth authenticated username and role as supplied by the user through their web browser.

The client is untrusted HTML/JavaScript so I can't store the name client side and send it with each request.

In APEX the call would be V('APP_USER') but that doesn't work with ORDS.

Comment: you want to know the schema/db user that your restful service is attached to, or you want to know the db user that was used to access the protected service?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith The schema and db user are both ORDSTEST (you can get the db user from sys_context('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') ).  I'm looking for what might be called the "ORDS Authenticated user" which is the user created by 'java -jar ords.war user "hr_admin" "HR Administrator"' command in the example.  ORDS presents a password challenge screen which, using the hr_admin credentials, allows you to access the REST endpoints.

Comment: you may have to use in bind params, REMOTE_USER is the http header.
so bind that to :rm or something

Comment: @thatjeffsmith From Firefox/Firebug I see request headers set by the browser and User-Agent is one.  To verify my setup I created IN bind for User-Agent, created a service "SELECT :useragent FROM dual" and it worked fine.  However 'REMOTE_USER' is not in the Headers sent by the browser (ords.war adds them on the way through?) so I don't know the exact name.  I tried binding to REMOTE_USER, REMOTE-USER, HTTP_REMOTE_USER, HTTP-REMOTE-USER, REMOTEUSER, X-REMOTE-USER, X_REMOTE_USER, APP_USER, X-Auth-User and others but all were NULL.  How do I find out what headers ORDS.war adds?